# Laravel routing: /seo-path-here to LandingPageController@getPage(3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have a website (using Laravel 4) where I want to build landing pages for ad campaigns.  At first, I want to have just a single landing page view.  But its H1 tag and some other content needs to match whatever ad brought the user there.  The many different ads I'll run will point to different routes.  For example, if I have 3 ads (with 3 different headlines), their destinations will be:

- mysite.com/great-deal
- mysite.com/buy-now
- mysite.com/two-for-one

How can I set up routes such that those 3 paths would point to my LandingPageController's getPage function and pass a unique argument?

For example, /great-deal would call getPage(1) while /buy-now would call getPage(2) and /two-for-one would call getPage(3).  I already have a process within getPage() to then feed the appropriate headlines/content into the view based on that argument.

I would know how to do it if I were willing to use mysite.com/x/great-deal, but I don't want the additional segment (were 'x' would be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a route like following in your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('{page}', array('as' => 'page', 'uses' => 'LandingPageController@getPage'));
```

Now create the `getPage` method in your controller like this:

```
public function getPage($page)
{
    // $page will contain the page slug used in the url
    // for example, great-deal for mysite.com/great-deal
}
```

So, any `url` with a single argument like `mysite.com/great-deal` or `mysite.com/1` will be routed to `getPage` method and the argument passed in the url will be available in the $page` variable.

You may also filter the `url` using `where` method, for example:

```
Route::get('{page}', array('as' => 'page', 'uses' => 'LandingPageController@getPage'))
->where('page', 'great-deal|buy-now|two-for-one');
```

So, only these arguments will match with the route but other argument passed in the `url` won't match, for example, `mysite.com/1` won't match.